# mysql where statement

Tags: mysql

```
category    item
red         pen
red         ball
blue        kite
blue        toy
shiny       pen
```

I want to get all items that are red OR blue AND they have to be shiny.

Here is my query so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT item FROM mytable WHERE category IN ("red","blue")
```

This get all of the red and blue items but how can I specify that the item must also be shiny? Adding shiny to the IN statement would still return all the blue items. The blue items should be excluded because none of them have a shiny entry in the database.

With my example, only pen should be returned. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't solved it yourself, check my answer below for tips and a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do self join the table, but remember that self join is very slow when the table size get increased. You should consider normalizing your table.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
select item from mytable where category = "red" or item = "blue"
intersect
select item from mytable where category = "shiny";
```

The first select make a set of all the red or blue elements, the second select make a set of all shiny elements. As you want to keep only those who are in the two set, you just have make the intersection between the two set.

http://sql.1keydata.com/fr/sql-intersect.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the table to itself.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mytable1.item FROM mytable mytable1
INNER JOIN mytable mytable2 ON mytable1.item=mytable2.item
WHERE mytable1.category IN ("red","blue") AND mytable2.category="shiny"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
      mt.item
   from
      MyTable mt
   group by 
      mt.item
   having 
          sum( if( mt.category = "shiny", 1, 0 ) ) = 1
      and sum( if( mt.category in ( "red", "blue" ), 1, 0 )) > 0
```